# Global minimum and local minimum question and proof of $x^2$ local minimum at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We defined $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a global maximum in $x_0 \in [a,b]$ on $[a,b]$ if $x \neq 0 \implies f(x) < f(x_0)$

Then we also defined local maximum:

$f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a local maximum $x_0 \in (a,b)$ if there $\exists \epsilon >0$ that such that $0<|x - x_0| < \epsilon \implies f(x) < f(x_0)$

> Would the same definition work for local minimum just by turning the inequality sign from $f(x) < f(x_0)$ to $f(x_0) < f(x)$, and everything else in the definition stays the same?}

> Another question would be, why does $x_0$ in the definition of the local maximum need to be an interior point (in an open interval)?

Now if I would think of a problem where I could use this definition, let's say $x^2$ has a local and a global minimum at $x = 0$. Let's prove it by definition:

$$x^2 > x_0 \iff x^2 > 0 \iff |x^2| > |0| \iff |x| > 0 \iff |x - 0| < \epsilon $$

If my proof is correct, this would mean that $|x - 0| < \epsilon \implies x^2 > 0$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I have removed the tag.

Comment: Yes, you can define minima by flipping the inequalities.  Yes $0$ is both a local and a global minimum of $f(x) = x^2.$  The endpoint of a closed interval may correspond to a global minimum that is not a local minimum.

Comment: @DougM But the epsilon neighbourhood stays the same right, the inequality does not flip there if I understand correctly ?

Comment: Yes $|x-x_0| < \epsilon$ still holds, it is the inequalities comparing $f(x)$ to $f(x_0)$ that would flip.